# Randomize only a portion of query results

Tags: mysql

I am sorting the prices in a database table from lowest to highest.
However, when there are duplicate prices I would like to randomize those results instead of having them output in the order they were created.

```
    ie
Not random
    id:1   $9.00
    id 2: $12.00
    id 3: $12:00
    id 4: $12.00
    id 5: $14.00

randomized
    id:1   $9.00
    id 3: $12.00
    id 2: $12:00
    id 4: $12.00
    id 5: $14.00

randomized
    id:1   $9.00
    id 4: $12.00
    id 2: $12:00
    id 3: $12.00
    id 4: $14.00

randomized
    id:1   $9.00
    id 2: $12.00
    id 4: $12:00
    id 3: $12.00
    id 4: $14.00

etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY price, rand()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by multiple expressions, simply by listing them one after the other. If two rows match on the first expression, they will be sorted by the second.

```
ORDER BY price, RAND()
```

This should pretty much do what you want.

Comment: Don't forget to accept a correct answer, for later visitors :)